# ng-model not working Angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to update a parent scope in a nested ng-repeat loop but it doesn't work ! I have literally been on this for the 2 pass hours !

This is my nested loop:

```
<div ng-repeat="input in config" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
    <div ng-repeat="inputProperty in input.inputStyle" style="border: 1px solid  #000;">
        <input type="text" style="{{inputProperty.style}}" ng-model="loop.year">Type in Year</div>
</div>
```

Filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="book in products | filter: loop.year">{{ book.bookname }}</div>
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dcot7eof/

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve and what is the problem?

Comment: Where is the `loop` defined?

Comment: If you are trying to dynamically build html that is defined by a json model then you should consider using a directive with the $compile method.

Comment: @CorySilva hello cory, thanks for the insight, but currently, i am currently almost done with the website ! the code i presented above was just an example of a problem i was having. Is it bad practice to load that json file and have if statements in the html saying if `input == 'text'` the input should be a text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loop.year` inside the nested loop and `loop.year` in the filter are two different things.

In the nested loop, when you write `ng-model="loop.year"`, Angular looks up the scope hierarchy for such a variable and doesn't find it, so it creates it, *on the scope of the nested loop*.

In the filter, you are trying to read the variable, so Angular looks up the scope hierarchy for the variable, but doesn't find it because the variable created in the nested loop is *downward* in the hierarchy, not upward. In other words, the scope the filter is in is a parent of the scope of the nested loop.

As others have said, to fix the issue, add `$scope.loop = { year: '' }` in your controller. This will add the variable to the controller's scope. As a consequence, when Angular looks up the scope hierarchy for `loop.year`, it will resolve it in both cases to the same variable.

You can avoid this type of issues all together if you use the ['Controller As' syntax](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/docs/api/ng/directive/ngController), which is new in Angular 1.2. This syntax makes it easier to manage scope variables. Here's what your view code looks like using this syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="input in ctrl.config" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
        <div ng-repeat="inputProperty in input.inputStyle">
            <input ng-model="ctrl.loop.year">Type in Year</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="book in ctrl.products | filter: ctrl.loop.year">{{ book.bookname }}</div>
```

Note how the `ng-controller` differs from your original code, and how variables are prefixed with `ctrl`. You can choose any name in place of `ctrl`. Here's the controller side:

```
function MyCtrl() {

    this.products = [{
        "bookname": "harryporter",
            "year": "2000"
    }, {
        "bookname": "Sleepless",
            "year": "2003"
    }];

    this.config = [{
        "Title": "YearInput",
            "width": "100",
            "inputStyle": [{
            "style": "background-color:green;"
        }]
    }];

};
```

`$scope` is replaced by `this`. However, `this` is not the same as the `$scope`. `this` is here bound to the `$scope.ctrl`.

This way of doing things helps to make the view code more explicit and easier to maintain, since you can immediately see what controller controls what variables.

Answer (score 1):

Add $scope.loop={}; to the controller.  You are setting a property on undefined.  Angular fails silently in these matters.

Comment: OMGGGGG !!! thank you so much, i was freaking out that i couldnt fix it T_T <- tears of joy !

Answer (score 1):

add this to your code:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.loop = {year:""};  // <---- add this
```